# Magento : how to remove right sidebar from catalogsearch page

Tags: magento

I want know that how to remove right sidebar from catalog search page in Magneto. It is not any another pages, its only cataog search page.

Comment: I tried my changes on catalog, catalogsearch  pages

Comment: Could you post your code or give a more complete example?

Comment: i dnt want to see right sidebar on catalogsearch page

Comment: SO doesn't work like that. You should post what you have tried and point out the problems of your solution.

Comment: its will done by admin panel setting, and i dnt know how to change. have you worked on magento before

Answer (score -1, accepted):

open **catalogsearch.xml** of your active theme. if you are using base theme then you can find that `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout` here.

```
<reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

now search for `catalogsearch_result_index` and replace `3columns.phtml` to `2columns-left.phtml` or `1column.phtml`.

Comment: its in line:52, i changed it but it shows blank page

Comment: you are using quick search or advance search ?

Comment: its on index.php page. in the header part

Comment: which version of magento ?

Comment: its working for me. are you using default `rwd` theme or your own theme? 





I used this
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>